# Как работать с методами базового класса?

Tags: java, наследование

Создать базовый объект со свойствами — тип, ширина, высота и методами для расчета площади в зависимости от типа (прямоугольник, окружность, треугольник). Создать объект на основе базового со свойствами — наименование, высота и методами для расчета объема.

---

Cоздал я базовый объект, только как работать с методами? Например, я не могу понять, как найти площадь окружности, если имеется ширина и высота. Помогите, разобраться. (И второе условие не пойму, как объём рассчитывать?)

```
public class figure {

private String Type;
private int Length;
private int Width;

public figure(String Type, int Length, int Width) {
    this.Type = Type;
    this.Length = Length;
    this.Width = Width;
}
public String getType() {
    return Type;
}
public int getLength() {
    return Length;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return Width;
}
public void getType(String Type) {
     this.Type = Type;
}
public void getLength(int Length) {
     this.Length =Length;
}
public void getWidth(int Width) {
     this.Width = Width;
}
public int getPryamoygolnik() {
    return Length * Width;
}
public int getTreygolnik() {
    return (Length * Width)/2;
}
public void showInfo() {
    System.out.println("Тип - " + Type);
    System.out.println("Ширина - " + Length);
    System.out.println("Высота - " + Width);
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("Площадь Прямоугольника = " + Length * Width);
    System.out.println("Площадь Треугольника = " + (Length * Width)/2);
}
}
```

Comment: У вас не в Java проблема, а в понимании постановки задачи. Вам предлагают создать базовый класс, описывающий плоскую фигуру, затем создать несколько наследников, отличающихся способом расчета площади. Затем вам предлагают на основе базового класса создать новый класс, который имеет дополнительную характеристику в виде третье величины, что уже позволит расчитывать объем.

Comment: Судя по поставленному вопросу и написанному коду - вам скорее не ясна геометрия двух и трехмерного пространства... Более развернутый вопрос поставьте. Что бы использовать объект его нужно для начала проинициализировать и потом вызывать его методы

Comment: @a_gura а как я смогу потом посчитать объём, имея при этом из базового класса - ширину и высоту, а из наследника - ещё высоту?

Comment: @Алексей1010, судя по всему вам надо начинать с нуля, с учебников по программированию самого начального уровня... Вы не понимаете элементарных вещей, тыкаетесь наугад, даже по коду видно, что вы не понимаете что и зачем пишете. Что-то объяснять пока нет базовых знаний смысла не имеет :(

Answer (score 3):

```
я не могу понять, как найти площадь окружности, если имеется ширина и высота
```

В случае окружности, очевидно, высота равна ширине, и обе эти величниы равны диаметру. Надеюсь, как искать площадь круга, зная его диаметр, объяснять не надо :) В случае же эллипса высота и ширина будут его главными осями. Я бы даже сделал наоборот, вместо окружности базовая фигура - эллипс, а окружность - его частный случай, даже формулу вычисления площади переделывать не придётся: `PI*(a/2)*(b/2)`, где a и b - "ширина" и "высота".

P.S. Как правильно заметил [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), в общем случае делать эллипс базовым классом для окружности - [плохая идея](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)...

Comment: PI*(a/2)*(b/2) - а в java(NetBeans) как мне записать PI, он будет ругаться же...

Comment: Да как хотите, так и записывайте, значение числа "пи" же знаете? Ну или воспользуйтесь определением из [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI), например.

Comment: ну да, возвращаемое значение в тип double преобразовать и написать PI как 3.14))) а вот как в main написать значения ширины и высоты? чтобы в зависимости от типа программа выбирала нужные значения ширины и высоты?
у меня вот: 
public static void main(String[] args) {

        figure f;

        f = new figure("Прямоугольник", 30, 30);

        f.showInfo();

Comment: @klopp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: @VladD, а это в данном случае вот прямо так и важно? Мы просто вычисляем площадь, ничего больше :)

Comment: @klopp: Ай-яй-яй, мы же программисты! Код должен быть написан правильно, стоять века! (_ирония off_)

Comment: BTW, из глубин памяти всплыто, что даже в древнем досовском болрандс, там, где `initgraph()`, были отдельные функции `circle()` и `ellipse()` :-)

Comment: Создать объект на основе базового со свойствами — наименование, высота и методами для расчета объема. (Объём прямоугольника, окружности и треугольника???? О_о)